# Exact Match Domain Extension Value

Tags: domains, search-results, name

I'm looking forward to start a micro-niche blog. I have an exact match domain available in ".co" extension. If, for example, my keyword is "blue cone" so what would be a suitable domain name for me in terms of higher ranked SERPS?

```
cone.blue
```

or

```
bluecone.co
```

Comment: The one which gets best remembered. Url isn't a big factor.

Comment: Yes, both are easy. But ".blue" is specifically associated for anything related to that color, so wouldn't it be a better option as it even omits two extra alphabets?

Comment: ".blue" is weird in my book, thus would not be remembered as domain name. I'd ".com" (or use the domain extention of your country)

Comment: What if there's no exact match ".com"? What's the closest equivalent alternate, ".co" maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is virtually no exact match domain name effect. There was a time that Google thought it was a good idea that exact match domain names be given a significant boost, however, that was a spammer's dream come true and Google saw the error of their ways, a bit slow of course.

The URL is a significant factor, however, not the way you think. Google does not make keyword matches. It does weight semantic value of HTML elements of the page as well as other factors such as the URL. In this, any apparent term match against a domain name would be the result of a weak search query result set and not for anyother reason. However, using semantics, it does strengthen the search engines ability to understand the site topic. Full stop. Keep in mind that the URL is a key factor in understanding the site topic semantically. For example, it is not expected that cheap-replacement-mop-heads.com would sell Samsung T.V.s.

In that regard, it is good if you sell blue cones to at least have bluecone.com. Semantically speaking, this makes sense. It is descriptive. Think back to your English class. However, cone.blue does not work as well semantically if at all. If you have cones for sale and they are all blue, how would you describe them? They are blue cones. Not cones blue.

Also think of marketing. Bluecones.com is far easier to remember. Yes the cones.blue is a hack, but will it really be easier to remember?? That is for you to decide since we do not have the real domain name to evaluate.