# Could it be good for SEO to use keyword rich domains under the .forsale TLD?

Tags: seo, domains, google-search, subdomain

One of the top level domain (TLD) that I came across ".forsale" caught my attention. If we are to buy "accessories" domain, and apply different subdomains like mobile, laptop would that have any SEO impact?  For
example:

- **laptop.accessories.forsale**
- **mobile.accessories.forsale**

The whole URL looks to be hugely keyword rich, for example "laptop accessories for sale"  and semantically correct and correlated.

Comment: See also: [Exact Match Domain Extension Value](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/91499/exact-match-domain-extension-value) and [Impact of switching from an exact match domain name (EMD) to a business name domain](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/114900/impact-of-switching-from-an-exact-match-domain-name-emd-to-a-business-name-dom)

Answer (score 4):

I think brand matters even if you're creating that kind of website. What percentage of people are going to buy from that kind of domain?  I don't think it will be many.

It's not easy to remember that full domain name.  That will cause return visit traffic to be much less than if you had a strongly branded site.

See from Search Engine Journal: [How to Choose a Domain Name That Will Stand the Test of Time](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/how-to-choose-domain-name/252285/)

Answer (score 1):

Exact match domains still get a little bit of SEO value  if you are using a .com domain name.   Using any other top level domain extension would make no sense at all right now.

Like if you have `laptopdeals.com` that would be a great domain name instead of `laptopdeals.offers` or `laptopdeals.forsale`.

Comment: I'm not sure that exact match domains provide any SEO benefit even for a .com these days.

Comment: It's hard to identify a noticeable difference if the content profile and the links profile is not good. I'm currently operating 2 emd website and they are doing good with only   less than 50 links for the home page. 
One of them is 9 months old 
and another one is 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

> If we are to buy "accessories" domain, and apply different subdomains like mobile, laptop would that have any SEO impact?

Google has not provided a hard line answer to that question, though they do have a couple old videos covering that topic:

[How important is it to have keywords in a domain name?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAWFv43qubI)

[Is Google putting more weight on brands in rankings?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMfWPWUh5uU)

In my experience working with such websites, having broad keywords within the domain name will not give you a leg-up in ranking for those terms.